# C# Word Interop: find.Execute() Throws exception if the found text is in a table

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I am developing a word automating application using .NET windows form application, The problem occurs when I call `range.Find.Execute()` on a text that is inside of a table cell.

Whenever I call it, a COMException is thrown like this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))'
```

The code that I'm using:

```
public void Replace(string textToFind, IWordDocumentWriter documentWriter)
{
    var range = WordApplication.ActiveDocument.Content;
    range.Find.ClearFormatting();
    range.Find.ClearHitHighlight();
    range.Find.Text = textToFind;
    range.Find.MatchWholeWord = true;
    range.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
    range.Find.Format = false;

    var find = range.Find;

    if (!find.Execute()) 
        return;

    range.Delete();
    documentWriter.Write(range);
}
```

I've looked for the `HRESULT: 0x80010105` meaning and it appears to be something happened in the COM library that I'm not able to fix from outside.

The template in question:

[image: Word screenshot]

Comment: On which line code is the exception thrown?  You should then inspect using the debugger.  Also calling delete on the range object before passing it as a variable to the documentWriter object seems iffy.

Comment: The exception is thrown on `if (!find.Execute())` , As for the delete, it is for clearing the range before writing anything in it's place.

Comment: no problems trying this myself (in vb.net). Few pointers: don't use variable names that match defined names ('Range' and 'Find') and add a variable type (so not 'var range' but 'var myrange'). Not sure this confirms the issue but it will rules out a possible cause.